# Bottom aligned div without disabling Bootstrap column floats

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I guess this might be impossible, but perhaps any expert can help me out with this. I'm trying to get a quite simple reponsive behaviour working:

A two columns layout, logo left, navbar right. Now the navbar should be **aligned at the bottom of the second column** for bigger screens and **floating to the next line directly under the logo** on smaller screens.

Bigger screen:

[image]

Smaller screen:

[image]

I suppose this can be done only with JS so far, but maybe anyone knows a way to get this realized with pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="col1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        </div>

        <div id="col2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <div id="navbar">Navbar: tab 1 | Nav tab 2 | Nav tab 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 150px; color: white;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: blue; height: 30px; width: 100%; color: white;
}
```

I've set up a jsfiddle with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/m4s4uqhx/6/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sizes of your elements are **fixed** as in your example, you can do the trick with `padding-top`, and remove it when the screen is too small (`xs: <768px`).

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  #col2 {
    padding-top:70px;
  }
}
```

**[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Lr2b34/)**

---

Else, I guess you will have to write some JavaScript :)

Comment: Excellent, completely forgot about media queries at this point. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

set the height of col-2 similar to logo and set the navbar to position absolute and bottom 0 . replace your css with this solution

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

#col1 {
  //border: 1px solid darkred; padding: 0px; 
}
#col2 {
  //border: 1px solid darkblue; padding: 0px;
}
#logo {
  background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 150px; color: white; padding: 5px;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: blue; height: 30px; width: 100%; color: white; padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px){
 #navbar{
       position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
 }
 #col2{
   height: 100px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px){
 #navbar{
       position: relative;
 }
 #col2{
   height: auto;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact height of you logo then you can add a padding top to the #col2 div on bigger screens using media queries

> tablets and greater @media(min-width:778px){...}
>
> desktops and greater @media(min-width:992px){...}
>
> large screens @media(min-width:1140px){...}

Css example

```
@media(min-width:992px){
  #col2{padding-top:70px;}
}
```

Working example
http://www.bootply.com/SHj7pkKt80

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the columns are not equal height. CSS only offer a couple of options for equalising columsn heights. CSS Tables and Flexbox.

You can leave the floats in place but **flexbox** will override the floating to a certain extent.

Nevertheless, the impact can be minimal depending on your requirement.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XjogzB)

```css
#logo {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#col2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    </div>

    <div id="col2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <div id="navbar">Navbar: tab 1 | Nav tab 2 | Nav tab 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need of using flexbox when you know heigts of elements, but your code will do the trick, only in modern browsers that support flexbox

Comment: @ustmaestro Does the OP say the height of the elements is known?

Comment: look at example logo and navbar heights are known ;)

Comment: It's an **example**...nowhere does the OP say the heights are known.

Comment: Heights are known indeed, only width of div2 needs to be flexible. I guess it was already solved with Mistalis response. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Adding flex to class .row needs more browser think and draws. Like @StefanMüller said only 2 divs need to be flexible.

Comment: This can be done simple using @Mistalis answer or mine. Have a nice day!